# Rails 5 broke send_file method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, mime-types

I have recently upgraded my application to Rails 5 and my downloads stopped working. When I click download button, browser hangs and nothing happens.

```
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
  def download
    send_file(
      "#{Rails.root}/public/file.rtf",
      filename: "file.rtf",
      type: :rtf,
      disposition: "attachment"
    )
  end
end
```

I have rtf mimetype

```
Mime::Type.register "text/richtext", :rtf
```

Logs showing that everything is ok

```
Sent file /home/deploy/app/releases/20160518213049/public/file.rtf (0.4ms)
I, [2016-05-18T17:34:48.435946 #20202]  INFO -- : [d02e8ea3-53da-440d-b3b1-cc6bfd6524dc] Completed 200 OK in 17ms (ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers? Also, did you try to look into the devtools' network tab and see what's happening?

Comment: Yes, it happens in Safari, Chrome and Mozilla. Devtools showing GET 200 xhr 2s. Maybe it's worth to mention, that I use ActionCable

Comment: Oh yeah... You can't save files through ajax/ws calls yet :) A workaround would be to create an iframe and set its source to your download URL.

Comment: Actually, I was not making any ajax calls. It's just regulat link_to tag. However, turbolinks did. Adding `'data-turbolinks' => false` to `link_to` tag resolved this issue. Not sure why it had worked previously without this tag

Comment: That's very strange. I had the same problem this worked for me as well. Any issues open on github for this? Thanks for sharing the fix btw.

Comment: I have `data-no-turbolink => true` previously, looks like they changed it to `data-turbolinks  => false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was detailed in above comments, the solution is to disable the turbolinks for link_to. This can be done, for Turbolinks 5, as it is described  [here](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#disabling-turbolinks-on-specific-links) by using `data-turbolinks="false"`

```
<%= link_to "Foo", new_foo_path(@foo), data: { turbolinks: false } %>
```